# A cypher query to get two nodes with 0 records in some but with records in other one

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have a node Activist has a property email also a node Customer has a property email
i want to find an email exists in the nodes at the same time i tried this query

```
match(a:Activist{email:"youssef@gmail.com"}),
(c:Customer{email:"yousef@gmail.com"})
return a,c
```

in the db, I have a customer with this email and no activist with email , but when i get the result i see no records but i want to get the node that has this email

```
(no changes, no records)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating `Cartesian Product`, that's why it's giving 0 records. Simply, use `optional match`, for both the nodes, like this:

```
optional match(a:Activist{email:"youssef@gmail.com"})
optional match(c:Customer{email:"yousef@gmail.com"})
return a,c
```

Comment: Also check the `email` I believe there is a typo